# Deleting page from PDF - while using LINENUMBERS for counting the number of lines in a text

Tags: linenumber

Using linenumbers environment helps me to count the number of lines as shown. With "\lastlinenumber" it is possible to save the number of lines which i need to operate with on the NEXT PAGE.

My Problem:

I need ONLY THE NEXT PAGE, so i want that the first page is not in the PDF. But unfortunately, to let latex calculating "\lastlinenumber", i need to add a page with the content.

How can i remove the entire first page, but still get the "\lastlinenumber" for further operations?

[image]

Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[german]{article}%border=10mm 
\usepackage[left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm]{geometry}
\parindent=0pt
\setlength{\textwidth}{16.8cm}%
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{lineno} 
\newcounter{lastlineno}
\def\lastlinenumber{%
    \setcounter{lastlineno}{\value{linenumber}}%
    \addtocounter{lastlineno}{-1}%
    \thelastlineno}

\begin{document} 
\eject \pdfpagewidth=16.8cm \pdfpageheight=2cm 

 \begin{addmargin}[0mm]{0mm} 
    \begin{linenumbers}%
        \modulolinenumbers[1]%
        \resetlinenumber%
        text text
        
        blabla
        
        bubu
    \end{linenumbers}% 
\end{addmargin}

\lastlinenumber 


\eject \pdfpagewidth=16.8cm \pdfpageheight=2cm 

I want to operate with \lastlinenumber on this page

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[german]{article}%border=10mm 
\usepackage[left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm]{geometry}
\parindent=0pt
\setlength{\textwidth}{16.8cm}%
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{lineno} 
\newcounter{lastlineno}
\def\lastlinenumber{%
    \setcounter{lastlineno}{\value{linenumber}}%
    \addtocounter{lastlineno}{-1}%
    \thelastlineno}
\begin{document} 

\AddToHookNext{shipout/before}{\DiscardShipoutBox}
 \begin{addmargin}[0mm]{0mm} 
    \begin{linenumbers}%
        \modulolinenumbers[1]%
        \resetlinenumber%
        text text
        
        blabla
        
        bubu
    \end{linenumbers}% 
\end{addmargin}

\lastlinenumber 


\newpage
\pdfpagewidth=16.8cm \pdfpageheight=2cm 

I want to operate with \lastlinenumber on this page

\end{document}
```